# How to make a search bar do PHP search for only one aspect of a table

Tags: php

I am doing basic work for peanuts to gain experience, and a client asked for a search bar. Simple enough, I used this:

```
</form>
        <form method="get" id="search_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="tblName" value="<?php echo $tableName; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="pageno" value="1" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['search'])) echo $_GET['search']; ?>" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

They want it to search their data by city, which is fine, and it works, but they ONLY want it to search the cities. For example, if the user searches for "Chicago", it should only return facilities in Chicago, not necessarily people named "Chicago", or facilities outside that city with "Chicago" in their name. How can I modify the php to only search one table in the database?

EDIT: I know such a thing is bad practice, because the only search results I could get were for people saying not to do this, but the client is rather insistent, so I figure I should do what they ask.

The search code they have in place is this:

```
<div class="row mt-20 table_section">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <?php 
                $tableHtm = '';
                $pagenationui = '';

                $sql_getcolumn = "SELECT *
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE TABLE_NAME='".$tableName."'";
                $colResult = $conn->query($sql_getcolumn);

                if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
                    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
                } else {
                    $pageno = 1;
                }
                $no_of_records_per_page = 15;
                $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;

                $total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `".$tableName."`";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
                if (isset($result->num_rows) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
                    $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
                    $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
                }

                // thead start-----------------------------
                $tableHtm .= '<thead></tr>';

                $columnAry = [];
                if ( isset($colResult->num_rows) && $colResult->num_rows > 0) {
                    $tableHtm .= '<th></th>';
                    while($columnrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($colResult)) {
                        if( $columnrow['COLUMN_NAME'] != 'iid' ){
                            $tableHtm .= '<th>'. $columnrow['COLUMN_NAME'] .'</th>';
                            $columnAry[] = $columnrow['COLUMN_NAME'];
                        }
                    }
                    // $tableHtm .= '<th width="40px"><a href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></th>';
                }
                $tableHtm .= '</tr></thead>';
                // thead end-----------------------------


                $where = '';
                if( isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search']) ){
                    if (count($columnAry) > 0) {
                        foreach ($columnAry as $key => $columnrow) {
                            if( $key == 0 ){
                                $where .= " WHERE `".$columnrow."` LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' "; 
                            }else {
                                $where .= " OR `".$columnrow."` LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' "; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$tableName ."`". $where ." LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$no_of_records_per_page."";
                $res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


                if (isset($res_data->num_rows) && $res_data->num_rows > 0) {
                    $kkk = 0;
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_data)) {
                        $tableHtm .= '<tr rowid="'. $row['iid'] .'">';
                        if (count($columnAry) > 0) {
                            $tableHtm .= '<td><input type="checkbox" class="rowid" value="'.$row['iid'].'"></td>';
                            foreach ($columnAry as $key => $columnrow) {
                                $tableHtm .= '<td>'. $row[ $columnrow ] .'</td>';
                            }
                            // $tableHtm .= '<th><a href="javascript:;" title="edit" class="edited" rowid="'. $row['iid'] .'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></th>';
                        }
                        $kkk++;
                        $tableHtm .= '</tr>';
                    }

                    $st_nxt_cla = ''; 
                    $st_pre_cla = ''; 
                    $pagenum = '';
                    if($pageno <= 1){ 
                        $st_pre_cla = 'disabled'; 
                        $st_pre_link = '#'; 
                    } else { 
                        $st_pre_link = "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); }
                    if($pageno >= $total_pages){ 
                        $st_nxt_cla = 'disabled'; 
                        $st_nxt_link = '#'; 
                    } else { 
                        $st_nxt_link = "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); }

                    $pagenum .= '<li>
                            <a href="javascript:;" id="pageid_li"><input type="number" name="pageno" value="'. (isset($_GET['pageno'])?$_GET['pageno']:1) .'" /> of '. $total_pages .'</a>
                        </li>';

                    $pagenationui='<ul class="pagination">
                                    <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
                                    <li class="'.$st_pre_cla.'">
                                        <a href="'.$st_pre_link.'">Prev</a>
                                    </li>'. $pagenum .'
                                    <li class="'.$st_nxt_cla.'">
                                        <a href="'.$st_nxt_link.'">Next</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="?pageno='.$total_pages.'">Last</a></li>
                                </ul>';
                } else {
                  $tableHtm .= '<div style="width:100%; text-align:center;">No results</div>';
                }
                echo $tableHtm;
             ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

There are many people working on this, and they want to have multiple different types of search bars for internal use. So I think I just need to copy and modify this so it somehow just works on the one search bar. I appreciate the help and patience so far.

Comment: Surely your search query in that case only needs to retrieve rows where the City matches the search term, rather than searching in any column? Or does your user's database table have a non-normalised layout and store multiple values in a single column? Show us the search code.

Comment: We need to see your SQL query here.

Comment: Part of gaining experience is learning to say "no" to a client when they ask for something unreasonable, and managing expectations for what can reasonably be implemented.

Comment: Thank you all for being nice, as I am obviously very new. Give me a moment to get my search code.

Comment: search code added.

Comment: Ah. That will automatically (on first glance) search all columns in all tables for the search value. You would need a separate search IMO, which only looks in the "City" column in the required table, or in all tables, if they all have one.

Comment: @droopsnoot yes, I thought it would be very easy, but nothing ever is, sadly.

Comment: You could always specify a different search variable (`citysearch` for example) and modify the search code so that if it sees `search`, it works the way it does, and if it sees `citysearch`, it only searches the place you need.

Comment: @droopsnoot Believe it or not, that is the first thing I tried! Same phrase and everything. I think I need to get used to where everything needs to be placed in relation to other things, but it is good to know I am barking up the right tree. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @TheCount beware that most of the hardest problems in computing are things that humans can intuitively "just do". You brain is an infinitely complex, self-programming quantum computer, your actual computer is just a really fast, complicated abacus.

Comment: Good tip, Sammitch, thank you!

Comment: @droopsnoot While I am familair with general SQL, the PHP is throwing me. What would you suggest I change in the SQL code above to just search the 'City' column, for example? I don't see anywhere to put, for example, ```SELECT * FROM table WHERE City = citysearch```

Comment: @droopsnoot oh, got it. different dialect. thanks again for the help! if you want to post an answer, I'd be happy to upvote and accept it.

Comment: That's OK, glad it's working for you now.